# How to change style attribute value with jquery at runtime

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is my `<img>` tag when screen size becomes 1199px:

```
<img id='rotateimage' src='images/01/0001.jpg' width='1200' height='700'>
```

I want to change the width and height, for example: `width: 1000; height:500` and decrease the width and height when the screen size becomes 1199px.

Here is what am doing, but it's not working:

```
if ($screen_width <= 1199){

    $width2 = 1000;
    $height = 500;

}

$("img").attr('width', '$width2');
$("img").attr('height', '$height');
```

Comment: Use jQuery's [.css() method](http://api.jquery.com/css/)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `CSS` for set your image size and use `$("img").css("width");` for modifications

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `.css()` function, as others suggested, or, you can define media queries in CSS.

### jQuery

```
function res() {
  if ($window.width() <= 1199) {
    $("#rotateimage").prop("width", 1000).prop("height", 500);
  } else {
    $("#rotateimage").prop("width", 1200).prop("height", 700);
  }
}

$( window ).resize(function() {
  res();
});
```

### Media queries in CSS

```
#rotateImage {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 700px;
}

 @media only screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
  #rotateImage {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
  }
}
```